# Reading JSON from Serial port missing part of the starting data

Tags: json, char, serial-port, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

When reading a JSON string from the serial port on an ESP8266 it cuts off the beginning of the data.

I have tried reading data from the Serial port and printing each character, however it is cutting off part of the begging of the data.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
      ;
  }
}

void loop() {
  int curSize = 30;
  char* buffer = new char[curSize];
  std::fill_n(buffer, curSize, 0);
  int pos = 0;
    Serial.print("Sending: ");
    while(Serial.available() == false) delay(500);
  while (Serial.available()) {
    char c = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(c);
     if(pos == curSize-1){
            char* newBuffer = increaseBuffer(buffer, curSize, curSize + 30);
            curSize += 30;
            delete[] buffer;
            buffer = newBuffer;
    }
    if(c == '\n'){
      buffer[pos] = 0;
      pos = 0;
      break;
    }
    buffer[pos++] = c;
  }
  if(buffer[0] != 0) {
    sendBuffer(buffer);
  }
  delete[] buffer;
}

char* increaseBuffer(char* orig, int oldSize, int newSize){
  char* data = new char[newSize];
  std::fill_n(data, newSize, 0);
  for(int i = 0; i < newSize; i++){
    if(i < oldSize) data[i] = orig[i];
    else data[i] = '\0';
  }
  return data;
}
```

JSON data used (and expected output)

```
{"type":0,"ver":"0.0.1","T":[28,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29],"H":[59.1608,59.1608,60,59.1608,60,60,60,59.1608,59.1608,59.1608],"DP":[20.36254,20.36254,20.59363,20.36254,20.59363,20.59363,20.59363,20.36254,20.36254],"HI":[30.90588,30.90588,31.0335,30.90588,31.0335,31.0335,31.0335,30.90588,30.90588]}
```

examples of what is actually output

```
Example 1: 9,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29],"H":[59.1608,59.1608,60,59.1608,60,60,60,59.1608,59.1608,59.1608],"DP":[20.36254,20.36254,20.59363,20.36254,20.59363,20.59363,20.59363,20.36254,20.36254],"HI":[30.90588,30.90588,31.0335,30.90588,31.0335,31.0335,31.0335,30.90588,30.90588]}
Example 2: 29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29],"H":[59.1608,59.1608,60,59.1608,60,60,60,59.1608,59.1608,59.1608],"DP":[20.36254,20.36254,20.59363,20.36254,20.59363,20.59363,20.59363,20.36254,20.36254],"HI":[30.90588,30.90588,31.0335,30.90588,31.0335,31.0335,31.0335,30.90588,30.90588]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the delay 1 instead of 500 in the blocking loop that's waiting for data to start coming in. I'm going to guess what happens is that on one iteration of that loop `Serial.available()` is false and during the delay you start to get data coming in that ends up getting written over by the time your delay ends to check again.

What I'm picturing is the following. If you were to expand out that delay(500) to be delay(1) called 500 times.

```
while(Serial.available() == false){
    delay(1);
    delay(1);
    // ...
    delay(1); // first character comes in 
    delay(1); 
    delay(1); // second character comes in
    // ... 
    delay(1); // n character comes in
}
```

Then after the delay is over you start actually collecting the characters that are coming in.